# When I push a field of a JavaScript array to another, the field also be pushed to the root array

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

I have following code:

```
var oldArr = { "filed1" : "abcde", "filed2" : "fghij", "anArray" : [["aaa1","bbb1"],["aaa2","bbb2"],["aaa3","bbb3"]]};
var newArr = oldArr;
var isFirst = false;

               for(var i = 0; i < oldArr.anArray.length; i++){
                    var indexA = oldArr.anArray[i].indexOf("aaa1");
                    var indexB = oldArr.anArray[i].indexOf("bbb1");

                    if(indexA > -1 && indexB > -1){
                        if(i == 0){
                            isFirst = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        newArr.anArray.push(oldArr.anArrray[i]);
                    }
                }
```

Everytime I add an field to newArr.anArray it will also add the field to oldArr.anArray

Is my code wrong or is ther a dependence between newArr and oldArr?

Comment: Yes, there's a depedence, they are the same array, or object actually.

Comment: `var newArr = oldArr;` -> `newArr` gets a reference to `oldArr`, it is not a new object.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: You would have to deep copy the object

Comment: And how do I do this?

Comment: `function makeArr() { return [ ... ]; }; var oldArr = makeArr(); var newArr = makeArr()` Make a function that returns the object, and make two copies of it by calling the function twice. And BTW `{ }` are objects and `[]` are arrays.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/5344074#5344074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could to this:

```
var newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldArr));
```

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-to-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) (If the object does not contain functions)

Comment: Still logging `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined(…)`

Comment: Link to jsfiddle / plunkr please so i can test

Comment: You have three 'r' in anArrray: `newArr.anArray.push(oldArr.anArrray[i]);`. Use console of your browser to debug.

Comment: _"You have three 'r' in anArrray"_ `js` at OP contains same three "r" characters

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as I use a constructor for both objects.
So there is no dependence between those objects.